# Please help me find the error in a pygame code for Tetris?

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a Tetris game using Pygame. However, instead of calling a single shape, but code calls all the functions for the shapes randomly one after the other. I tried calling `NewShape` at different places, but nothings working. If it calls a single shape, then the keyboard control does not work.

```
x=50
y=50
def ShapeL(screen,x,y):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, Cyan, [x,y-50,50,150])
    pygame.draw.line (screen,Cyan, [x, y], [x+50,y])
    pygame.draw.line (screen,Cyan, [x, y+50], [x+50,y+50])
    pygame.draw.line (screen,Cyan, [x, y+100], [x+50,y+100])
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, Cyan, [x+50,y+50 ,50,50])

ShapeChosen=False
def NewShape(screen,x,y):
    ListShapes=[ShapeS, ShapeT, ShapeL, ShapeI, ShapeSquare]
    Shape=random.choice(ListShapes)(screen,x,y)#chooses random shape
    ShapeChosen=True

def BasicGame(x,y):
    Done=False
    while not Done and y!=500 and ShapeChosen!=True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                Done=True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key ==pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x=x-50
                elif event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x=x+50
                elif event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y=y+50
                elif event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:
                    y=500
            if x==0:#Borders so the shape doesn't leave the screen.
                x=50
            elif x==400:
                x=350
            if y==550:
                y=500
    screen.fill(White)
    NewShape(screen,x,y)
```

I tried passing the parameter `ShapeChosen` to the function, however, it did not work as well. I tried passing `global ShapeChosen`, but it prevents the keyboard functions from working.

Comment: Seems like an issue of accessing a global variable (`ShapeChosen=True` ) inside a function to me.

Comment: Re: your edit. As far as I'm aware Python passes booleans by value, not reference. Hence a parameter solution won't work. Try `global ShapeChosen` inside your function instead?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to modify your `NewShape` function so that it modifies the global variable `ShapeChosen` instead of creating a new global one.

```
ShapeChosen=False
def NewShape(screen,x,y):
    global ShapeChosen
    ListShapes=[ShapeS, ShapeT, ShapeL, ShapeI, ShapeSquare]
    Shape=random.choice(ListShapes)(screen,x,y)#chooses random shape
    ShapeChosen=True
```

Now, you mentioned that if you do so, the keyboard input stops working. I'm not really sure how you've planned your code to work here, but the line

```
while not Done and y!=500 and ShapeChosen!=True:
```

is obviously the issue, because the while-loop should stop as soon as `ShapeChosen` becomes true. I can't tell what your intention here is, but perhaps you would like to move the `ShapeChosen`-condition just above the call to `NewShape`? Something along the lines of

```
if not ShapeChosen:
    NewShape(screen, x, y)
```